# How to send an HTTPS link to telegram chat ID. using sendmessage ("https://---", chatID)

Tags: python

I like to send a link to my Telegram application-Bot using python#. so, While I send a text I can do it but I can't send Https or Http to my app chat. also, some links are also possible to send. also, I can print it in the terminal of pycharm

```
if text == "link":
sendMessage("https://www.bousai.pref.kanagawa.jp/K_PUB_VF_DetailCity?cityid=", chatId)
```

no error and no print in Telegram-app-Bot

Answer (score 0):

in the link we have (K_PUB_VF_) one 
when I remove _, _, _ then I can print it

the next question 
(How to do it with _ one not to be removed it)